# Python importing empty folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
/tmp# mkdir foobar
/tmp# python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 28 2017, 16:41:13) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foobar
>>>
```

Why python allows to import any random (including an empty) directory? So, in above the snap shot, am I importing a package OR a module?. Yes, 'foobar' is a folder but import target is always a module (.py file) isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are unwittingly creating a [*namespace package*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-namespace-package).

This <strike>bug</strike> ... ahem ... this [*feature*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxPtF.jpg) was introduced in Python 3.3+.

Details are in [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/).

Comment: Also, an additional question. In general, the target of an 'import' statement can be a module as well as a package? I was assuming only modules can be imported(including: from <package> import <module>)

Comment: Yes, the target of an import statement can be either a module or a package.

Comment: What an annoying feature.  Allowing no `__init__.py` means no `module.__file__`.  I can't find this "package"... where is it located??

Comment: @cowlinator  Look in `module.__path__` instead.  Careful, different parts of the package may be scattered around in different directories.

Comment: I didn't know about `.__path__`, that helped me, thank you.